# seo url would not open after shifting files to root dir from sub

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo

my current seo url was on sub dir which worked ok but after trying to use the script on root dir the link wont open

this is the articles.php codes

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url = str_replace('/', '', $url);

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE seo_url = :seo_url");
$stmt->bindParam(':seo_url', $url, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch();
$cou = $stmt->rowCount();

if($cou <1){
        header("Location: error.php");
        exit();
}
```

and my htaccess is

```
RewriteEngine On

# SEO URL Settings

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ articles.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

the code above redirects me to error.php page

earlier on sub folder it was something like this

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $url = str_replace('/test/', '', $url);
```

and

```
RewriteBase /test/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ articles.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Give a few example URLs which worked previously and aren't working now.

Comment: mate its mentioned above on post the second part which worked before

Comment: my stored url is like 1/state/city/some-text-for-title but with the first bit of code i get a / in front of my stored url like /1/state/city/some-text-for-title

Answer (score 0):

Your are replacing '/' from request uri using below code:

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url = str_replace('/', '', $url);
```

You should try to remove only last '/' (if seo_url field values are stored like "/some-dir/yourpage/" in database) from uri like:

```
$url = rtrim($url, '/');
```

Comment: Mate m trying to remove the first / my stored url is like 1/state/city/some-text-for-title but om article page when i echo in fron of 1 which is the id a / comes from where i don't know so the url becomes like /1/state/city/some-text-for-title and because of / at the beginning no results show from db

Comment: You can try `$url = ltrim($url, '/');` and it will satisfy the query and will give you the count.

Comment: /1/state/city/neque-porro-quisquam-est-qui-dolorem-ipsum-quia-dolor-sit-amet-consectetur
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'postID' cannot be null' in

Comment: still the / comes in front of 1